includegraphics error reading pdf
error:  (file ./Images/0.1.pdf) (pdf inclusion): reading image failed
./Homework.tex:194:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!Latexmk: Getting log file 'Homework.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'Homework.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'Homework.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):

I use lualatex (texlive 2024), this pdf is created by xspec https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/xanadu/xspec/manual/node42.html
https://paste.c-net.org/LusciousAirwaves
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{0.1.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


The linked file is given a download name of 0.1.pdf but it is not PDF it is PostScript. It starts
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%For: firestar
%%Title: PGPLOT PostScript plot
%%Creator: PGPLOT
%%CreationDate:  9-Jun-2024 22:05
%%BoundingBox: (atend)
%%Orientation: Landscape
%%Pages: (atend)
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog

rename it to file.eps  and use \includegraphics{file.eps}
